# Mysql Select if row had value greater than

Tags: mysql, sql

table `PUBLISHER`

`PB_ID`

table `BOOK`

`BK_ID`,`BK_PRICE`,`PB_ID`

1) I want to get list of all publisher who never had `BK_PRICE  > 10`

2) I want to get list of all publisher who never had `BK_PRICE  < 10`

Comment: `Not exists` is your friend.  Show us what you've tried and failed with and we'll point you in the right direction.  This is a pretty straightforward query so I'd like to see where you had problems.

Comment: Simply join those two tables n give condition.. u will get what u needed

Comment: `SELECT PUBLISHER.PB_ID FROM PUBLISHER INNER JOIN BOOK ON BOOK.PB_ID = PUBLISHER.PB_ID WHERE BK_LIST_PRICE < 10 GROUP BY PUBLISHER.PB_ID` dont work like rest of answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other responses using a join, this can early exist the subquery once a price is found to be > or < than the 10 for a given publisher.  Additionally each of the other responses would give you false results since a publisher would  only need have one book above or below 10 to be included on the list. 
 Additionally since there isn't a join you don't get the pub_ID repeated for each book over or less than 10 and eliminates the need for a distinct.

However, if you need data from Book, then a join is necessary and this approach will not work.  But in terms of performance, this method should be the fastest assuming proper indexing on keys

As i'm unclear if you want one data set or two, I used 'union ALL' (which doesn't execute a distinct; so less of a performance hit) the results and added a pubClass column to denote which publishers have 'noBookPrice>10' and those having 'noBookPrice<10'

This uses a correlated subquery (notice how P. is referenced in the SUBquery?  How does the subquery even know about P? (that is cool rated subquery and can only be one level deep) to combine the list of {P} and the results of {b} to ensure a publisher doesn't have a single occurrence of a book price > 10 or < 10.

```
SELECT P.Pub_ID, 'NoBookPrice>10' as PubClass
FROM Publisher P
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Book B 
                  WHERE BK_PRICE > 10 
                    and B.PB_ID = P.Pub_ID)
UNION ALL

SELECT Pub_ID, 'NoBookPrice<10' as PubClass
FROM Publisher P
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Book B 
                  WHERE BK_PRICE < 10 
                    and B.PB_ID = P.Pub_ID)
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer . lol everyone was jumping like yo this shit is easy (it is easy tho just twisted) and answered wrong.

Comment: It's why I posted `NOT Exists` is your friend in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

```
SELECT PB_ID
     FROM PUBLISHER
    WHERE PB_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PB_ID  
      FROM BOOK        
    WHERE BK_PRICE >= 10 );
```

## 2

```
SELECT PB_ID
  FROM PUBLISHER
 WHERE PB_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PB_ID 
      FROM BOOK
     WHERE BK_PRICE <= 10 );
```

Comment: Check the new ans n let me know

Comment: still wrong answer lol . its solved anyways check above your answer there is answer

Comment: if a publisher has a book priced at 9 and one that is priced at 11, your query would return that publisher and should not.

Comment: Sure.  say publisher 123 has two books: {A, B}
.  A is priced at $9.00 B is priced at $11.00.  This publisher would be returned in both your queries. it should be in neither.  Why? The question is: I want to get list of all publisher who ***never had*** BK_PRICE  > 10... In the first query since Book B is >10 the publisher shouldn't be listed even though it had 1 book at 9.  and the vice-versa for the other query.  if publisher 456 had two books {C,D} and both priced $9.00 then it should be in your first query. and if publisher 789 had books {E,F} priced at $11.00 then it should be in 2nd qry

Comment: I understand that my sql is wrong... Does having help in such cases....? pls check my new ans...

Comment: No.  The having clause really helps when aggregation is involved.  There is no aggregation needed here. If you were to use NOT in, you'd be closer.  `Select * from publisher where pb_ID not in (Select pb_ID from Book where bk_price >=10)` for first question and `Select * from publisher where pb_ID not in (Select pb_ID from Book where bk_price <=10)` for the second.  The subquery in the first query shows only those books haging a price >=10.  if a publisher is in that list then we don't want them thus the 'NOT' vise-versa for 2nd query. but in/Not in is slow in this approach thus `not exists`

Comment: +1 for taking the time to understand why your response needed corrections.  I hope my comments have helped!  Build a data with books and prices aforementioned.  if you get more than publisher 456 and 789, then something is still wrong!

Comment: Thank u...Any good tutorials to understand the mysql query optimizations with examples.

Comment: I learned though experience; and building my own tests to prove things out. I don't really have good tutorials in my repertoire.  In general test to find out what's best in your situation; dbengines now a days will even parse vastly different SQL to the same plan as its the most beneficial.   Know that as data changes so might the execution plans and the quality of the results so what may be good for the first year, may lack performance in years 2 and beyond thus a revisit is needed!  All of these things impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query

```
Select P.PB_ID from PUBLISHER P join BOOK B on P.PB_ID = B.PB_ID where B.BK_PRICE  > 10
```

Your 2nd query

```
 Select P.PB_ID from PUBLISHER P join BOOK B on P.PB_ID = B.PB_ID where B.BK_PRICE  < 10
```

Comment: Say I have a publisher with two books.  One priced 9 the other priced 11.  Should it be returned in either result set? (no)  would it on your two queries (yes).